# Is there a shortcut in Sketch to make 2 elements switch places?

Tags: sketch-app

Is there a shortcut in Sketch to make 2 elements switch places?

I want to select 2 elements and swap their locations. Is there a shortcut to this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a handy plugin made by [interacthings](https://github.com/interacthings) to do just that!

Download it from their Github [here](https://github.com/interacthings/swap-elements)!

A few more options are [Sketch-Mate](https://github.com/getflourish/Sketch-Mate) and [Cemre's Sketch Plugins](https://github.com/cemre/cemre-sketch-plugins).

Here's a screenshot of Sketch-Mate in action:

[image]